What does $1/C_{eq}= 1/C_1+ 1/C_2 + 1/C_3+\ldots$ mean?
This question arises from the equivalent capacitance formula in series circuits and i was wondering what adding capacitors in this special addition form mean in the context of series circuits to be precise my problem is how we landed on this formula and what the addition represents.

Are you asking how the formula for the total capacitance of capacitors in series is derived?

Well, I'll take a stab. @Ruffolo provided a fantastic answer, and you hit back with "but still what does it mean?".
I think you're just going to need to think harder as to what adding things arithmetically, geometrically, quadratically, and harmonically.
Arithmetically is how you add simple things: paychecks, hamburgers, no-scope headshots, and so on.
Quadratically is how you add things that are uncorrelated: distances in independent dimensions (see: Pythagorus), statistical errors (see: error propagation), and the combination of those two things: Brownian motion/random walk distance.
Geometrically: This is used mostly to find an geometric average, so: spectral flatness in signal processing, indices of refraction for antireflective coatings ($n_{ar} = \sqrt{n_1 n_2}$), ellipse areas ($\pi r^2 \rightarrow \pi a b $).
Harmonically: So @Ruffolo broke it down as actually physical construction, which I like. You didn't follow it, so there are several way to proceed.
Since we're looking at basic circuit stuff, maybe consider resistors in series: they add arithmetically, and that can be explained physically. Suppose I have one 8 ohm resistor that a can draw:
$$ \rightarrow[\rm{X X X X X X X X}]\rightarrow$$
I can just say: no, that's two 4 ohm resistors:
$$ \rightarrow[\rm{X X X X}][{\rm X X X X}]\rightarrow$$
that clearly add arithmetically.
Very simple, why am I doing this? Well, imagine if the standard in LCR-circuits was to call them LC$\Sigma$-circuits. For some reason we called resistors "conductors" and measure them by their conductivity $\sigma$?
Then my above cartoons would be describing a:
$$ \sigma_1 = \frac 1 8 \mho $$
circuit (element), which is then broken down into two conductors in parallel:
$$ \sigma_2 = \frac 1 {\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4} \mho $$
or, more simply:
$$ \frac 1 {\sigma_2} = (\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4) \mho $$
So when you ask "but what does it mean?", it means we're adding things that are inverse of things we can intuitively add arithmetically.
Nevertheless, I understand why you're a bit lost: as far as I can remember, I have never has this explained in a class, we're just told: caps add harmonically.
Then when we take standardized tests, we get questions where harmonic addition is required, e.g. "It take Alice 20 minutes to make 5 widgets while Bob can make 7 in 30 minutes, how long does it take Alice and Bob to make 12 widgets?" and of course one of the answer choices is 25 minutes.
No, but fr, when I finally learned this I was looking at polarization half-lives. We had a polarized $^3$He and in a simplified$^1$ version, let's just say it had two ways to become depolarized. Process 1 had a lifetime of $\tau_1$, and process 2 was $\tau_2$: what's the actually lifetime?
Well you can't add half-lifes, but you can add rates:
$$ \frac 1{\tau} =  \frac 1{\tau_1} + \frac 1{\tau_2}$$
or
$$ \omega = \omega_1 + \omega_2 $$
Rates add arithmetically, times add harmonically.
So in the capacitor case, $C$ represents some kind of rate. (I've always struggled to remember what $C$ means, so I may get this backwards.) I think it's the rate at which you store charge at constant voltage...or it's the rate at which you generate voltage at fixed charge...you'll need to think about it.
[1] The actual problem was hard in that the two processes occurred at different parts of the system that were at different temperatures, but were physically connected. An analysis with half-lifes didn't work, but with rate it became a classic $2\times 2$ eigenvalue problem where populations were connected by a 2x2 ${\bf \omega}$ rate matrix. Very neat.

thanks dude your explanation was on spot for me , I would just like to add a thing here , what appealed to me more when thinking about the "things we can intuitively add" I liked using charges for parallels ( where Qi = CixV ) so the total charge is Q=(c1+c2+c...)xV or VxCeq and potential differences for series (Vi=Q/Ci) so that the total potential is V=Q/Ceq  once again my thanks to you and @Ruffolo

can you take a look at this problem please
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/834877/452229

Capacitance of a capacitor is defined as the ratio of charge in each of its conductors and the electric potential difference between them
$$
C =\frac QV
$$
For parallel plate capacitors, we could explicit show that the important parameters for capacitance is geometric parameters of the capacitor
$$
C = \varepsilon \frac Ad
$$
where $A$ is the plate area and $d$ is the distance between plates. If we increase the Area, the capacitance increase, and if we increase the distance, the capacitance decreases.
When we put capacitors in parallel in a circuit, the observable effect could be compared to sum their areas. Imagine that you place each of them side by side, all of them with the same potential difference, and let's say the same distance $d$ between plates. The area of the $n$-th capacitor is
$$
A_n = C_n \frac d\varepsilon 
$$
So the total area would be
$$
A = A_1+A_2+\dots A_n +\dots = \left (C_1+C_2+\dots C_n+\dots \right) \frac d\varepsilon
$$
And we see that all of them behaves like a single capacitor with effective capacitance
$$
C= C_1+C_2+\dots C_n+\dots
$$
Now, for capacitors in series, it is not the areas that sum up, but their plate distances. Imagine that all of them have the same plate Area. The total distance of the first plate of the first capacitor to the last plate of the last capacitor will be
$$
d = d_1+\dots d_n +\dots
$$
But the distance can be written as
$$
d_n = \varepsilon \frac AC_n
$$
Which implies that
$$
d = \varepsilon \left (\frac {A}{C_1}+\frac {A}{C_2}+\dots \frac {A}{C_n}+\dots \right) = \varepsilon \frac AC
$$
We see that all of them behave like a single capacitor with effective capacitance given by
$$
\frac 1C = \frac {1}{C_1 }+ \frac {1}{C_2 }+ \dots \frac {1}{C_n} +\dots
$$

but still what does it mean to add inverses mathematically

This expression is the definition of Harmonic Mean. You can check in this article some other places where it appears and possible geometrical meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean

For example, in a circuit, you need a $235 \mu F$capacitor at a voltage of 35 V, and you only have $470 \mu F$ capacitors, we know that if we put two $470 \mu F$ capacitors in series, their capacitance would be equivalent to a capacitor of capacitance $C_{eq}=\frac{C}{2}=235\mu F$, i.e. instead of putting one of $235\mu F$, we put two in series which are equivalent to it.

The other answers have started with the physical details of the capacitor and worked up. Let me look at how the capacitor behaves in a circuit and work down.
You should have learned that the impedance of a capacitor in a steady-state AC circuit is
$$Z_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}.$$
And you should have learned that when you have multiple components in series (any kind of components or any mix of components like an R, L, and C in series), their impedances add:
$$Z_{eq} = Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + ...$$
So if you have multiple capacitors in series in a circuit, their impedances add:
$$Z_{eq} = \frac{1}{j \omega C_1} + \frac{1}{j \omega C_2} + \frac{1}{j \omega C_2} + ... $$
So if you believe there must be some "equivalent capacitor" that would produce the same impedance as the series combination, then you'd have
$$Z_{eq} = \frac{1}{j\omega C_{eq}}$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{j\omega C_{eq}} = \frac{1}{j \omega C_1} + \frac{1}{j \omega C_2} + \frac{1}{j \omega C_2} + ... $$
Then you can just factor out $\frac{1}{j\omega}$ from both sides and you get your formula for the equivalent capacitance for a series combination of capacitors
$$\frac{1}{C_{eq}} = \frac{1}{C_1} + \frac{1}{C_2} + \frac{1}{C_3} + ...$$

what does adding mean in context[?]

It means you're adding up the impedances of the series capacitors, just like you'd do with any other components placed in series.
