Why do we only account for the electric field due to one side of the infinite conducting plane and not both?
Originally this question was going to be how can force pass through charges because I used to think that the solution for the above problem is that the force from the other side gets blocked and that this is always the case.
However when I thought about it again I realised that I encountered a lot of point charge and line problems where a force exists between two charges (or a charge and a line) on the same axis even though there is a charge (or a line ) between them on the same axis.

So what is exactly true here and what is the correct way to imagine this situation more precisely why did the force pass through point charges and lines and didn't pass through the infinite plane.

Please consider breaking up your question into paragraphs and sentences to make it more understandable.

All you do is find the combined field due to all charges, that has always been the case. It's not clear why/how you would assume a charge can block a field.

An infinite conducting plane contains a very large quantity of mobile charge. You don't actually know (unless you calculate it) the charge distribution in this kind of problem. For example, you can't assume the charge is uniformly distributed on the conductive sheet. Further, the distribution will change if you move any external charges around in the system.
The mobility of the charge allows the charge to redistribute in response to the field produced by the other charges in the system, and it will do so in such a way as to produce 0 field within the conductive region (this is probably what you mean by "blocking the field").
When you are given a problem where the positions of the charges are givens, then you can't assume the charges have redistributed to negate the field due to other charges. For this kind of problem you have to sum up or integrate the fields (calculated according to Coulomb's Law) due to the given charges.

I got your point about redistributing but in the case of the image above the lines ' as they are positioned ' don't need to redistribute to cancel out the fields (btw sorry if it's misleading but what's near the line is a point not a charge ) can you clarify this to me please .

@sayote, for the midpoint, if you sum up the field due to the two lines (as I discussed in my 3rd paragraph) you get 0. For any point that isn't halfway between the two charged lines, that wouldn't be true. The fixed charge lines don't "block the field" everywhere between them, there just happens to be one line where their effects are equal and opposite, giving 0 net field.

I am such a bad writer , sorry for wasting your time but what i meant is on the outside how can the line on the left contribute to the field like shouldn't it be canceled by the field from the second line

Because if you add up the fields produced by the two source charges, they add up constructively. Like I said in the first paragraph, the infinite conductive sheet "blocks fields" because it contains mobile charge that can redistribute appropriately. Your two line charges don't contain mobile charge, they are fixed charges, so you shouldn't expect them to "block" the field.

also another clarification when i mentioned the plate i forgot to say that it was stated to have a uniform charge distribution. so how does the fields interact here ( and if i am not mistaken if a charge came close to the plate it would alter the distribution right ? i guess i understand the forces case but i dont get how the fields interact)

@sayote, your title says "infinite conducting plate", not "infinite sheet of fixed charge". I answered the question you asked. If you want to ask a different question, make a new post.

That said, an inifinite sheet of fixed charge would not "block the field". You'd need to sum up its effect with whatever other charges are in the system just like in your example with two fixed line charges.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
